# Standardized Error Classification & Handling

Tags: handle, standardized

I need to standardize on how I classify and handle errors/exceptions 'gracefully'.

I currently use a process by which I report the errors to a function passing an error-number, severity-code, location-info and extra-info-string. This function returns boolean true if the error is fatal and the app should die, false otherwise. As part of it's  process, apart from visual-feedback to the user, the function also log-to-file errors of above some severity-level.

Error-number indexes an array of strings explaining the type of error, e.g.:'File access','User Input','Thread-creation','Network access', etc. Severity-code is binary OR of 0,1,2 or 4, 0=informative, 1=user_retry, 2=cannot_complete, 4=cannot_continue. Location-info is module & function, and Extra-info is parameter- and local variable values.

I want to make this into a standard way of error-handling that I can put in a library and re-use in all my apps. I mainly use C/C++ on Linux, but would want to use the resultant library with other languages/platforms as well.

- An idea is to extend the error-type
  array to indicate some default
  behavior for a given severity-level,
  but should this then become the
  action taken and give no options to
  the user?
- Or: should such extension be a
  sub-array of options that the user
  need to pick from? The problem with
  this is that the options would of
  necessity be generalized
  programming-related options that may
  very-well completely baffle an
  end-user.
- Or: should each app that uses the
  error-lib routine pass along its own
  array of either errors or default
  behaviors - but this will defeat the
  purpose of the library...
- Or: should the severity-levels be
  handled in each app?

Or: what do you suggest? How do you handle errors? How can I improve this?

Comment: C/C++ (on Linux) - I'll put answer in edited question - but my aim is a library to be used with any language (I also use perl, assembler, php, ...)

Comment: Wow, the way you are handling it is more robust than anything I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you handle the errors really depends upon the application.A Web application has a different Error-Catching mechanism than A Desktop Application, and both of those differ drastically to an asynchronous messaging system.

That being said the a common practice in error handling is to handle it at the lowest possible level where it can be dealt with. This usually means the Application Layer or the GUI.

I like the severity levels. Perhaps you can have a pluggable Error-collection library with different error output providers and severity level provider.

Output providers could include things like a logginProvider and IgnoreErrorsProvider.
Severity providers would probably be something implemented by each project since severity levels are usually determined by that type of project in which it occurs. (For example, network connection issues are more severe for a banking application than for a contact management system).

Comment: Good idea on making it a plug-in: this would work if the app/language/platform allows for it, and I could make the code portable enough. What would you suggest that I do to achieve that?

Comment: I would start simple and develop the framework as geared toward your current project. Then spike a project for a different platform (like  a desktop app if your current app is a web app or vice versa) and refactor the error handling to a form usable by both projects.

Comment: Ha! knew you were going to say something like that ;-)
(Like all programmers I'm lazy and always want to write God-Code: once for use everywhere (like genes))
but you're right - it's the refactoring way, or create a Mother-algorithm for all implementations.